# How to define a query which returns all documents with a same field

Tags: mongodb

I would like to create a query for checking which documents in my database have a same field value.

e.g. I got 100 documents stored and 2 of them looks like this:

**document 1:**

```
{
    "_id":32143242,
    "specialField":12
}
```

**document 2:**

```
{
    "_id":787878,
    "specialField":12
}
```

So how to get this two documents if I don't know the ids or the specialField-Value?

Comment: What have you trid? If you know the field names, I'd look at using the aggregation framework. Group, and count. If not, MapReduce.

Answer (score 0):

This is a grouping operation that can be performed using the [MongoDB aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#stage._S_group).

Sample Data

```
> db.foo.find().pretty();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515ead9c7bb40c6a51b16a68"), "Value" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515ead9d7bb40c6a51b16a69"), "Value" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515ead9f7bb40c6a51b16a6a"), "Value" : 14 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515eada07bb40c6a51b16a6b"), "Value" : 8 }
```

Sample Grouping operation

```
> db.foo.aggregate({$group : 
    { _id: "$Value", 
      count : {$sum : 1}, 
      ids: { $addToSet : "$_id" } } });
```

This will return groups of equal `Value` along with their count and the respective ids:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 8,
                        "count" : 1,
                        "ids" : [
                                ObjectId("515eada07bb40c6a51b16a6b")
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 14,
                        "count" : 1,
                        "ids" : [
                                ObjectId("515ead9f7bb40c6a51b16a6a")
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 12,
                        "count" : 2,
                        "ids" : [
                                ObjectId("515ead9d7bb40c6a51b16a69"),
                                ObjectId("515ead9c7bb40c6a51b16a68")
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

You should read the documentation of the aggregation framework and understand its limitations.

Comment: you should change $addToSet to $push, it'll be faster and you can't have duplicate _ids so $addToSet doesn't gain anything.